# Ember-cli wants watchman >3*, I have 4* but it still complains

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, watchman

After getting tired of seeing "Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events" I did `brew install watchman` and now get "Invalid watchman found, version: [4.5.0] did not satisfy [^3.0.0], falling back to NodeWatcher." yet 4.5.0 is > 3.0.0…?

Our app uses Ember 1.12.0 and Ember-cli 0.2.7.

I checked [ember-cli.com/#watchman](http://www.ember-cli.com/#watchman) ([that info is now here](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/)) but that just points out the Node has a similarly-named package, and suggests `npm uninstall -g watchman` - that's not the problem.

Finally `which -a watchman` yeilds two results:

```
/usr/local/bin/watchman
/usr/local/bin/watchman
```

Huh?

Anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: re: two results, you have `/usr/local/bin` listed in your `$PATH` twice.

Comment: @WezFurlong thanks, didn't spot that - `$PATH` fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update your `ember-cli` with `npm install -g ember-cli@1.13.15` which nicely manages any Ember 1.12 app and compatible with the latest watchmans.

`brew install watchman` is the right way to install WatchMan, so you have the right version. You can check it with `watchman -v`.

If you check your `/usr/local/bin` folder, probably you see only one watchman command, so it should be right.

Comment: I think upgrading `ember-cli` is the right call here.
`ember-cli` should really be using https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/capabilities.html rather than version number comparisons.